# Mock out instance variable/accessor for a class instance using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In our Rails application we have a third-party API (using Thrift) that we wrap with classes that can use multiple methods of retrieving data from the same instance and then adding that data into an instance variable/accessor.

For example we have a `BookManager` class like so:

```rb
class BookManager
  attr_accessor :token, :books, :scope, :total_count

  def initialize(token, scope, attrs={})
    @token = token
    @scope = scope
    @books = []
    @total_count = 0
  end

  # find all books
  def find_books
    @books = API.find_books(@token, @scope)
    @total_count = @books.count
  
    self
  end

  # find a single book by book_id
  def find_book_by_id(book_id)
    @books = API.find_book_by_id(@token, @scope, book_id)

    self
  end

  # find a single book by author_id
  def find_book_by_author_id(author_id)
    @books = API.find_book_by_author_id(@token, @scope, author_id)

    self
  end
end
```

So here we can get a list of books, or a single book by `book_id` or `author_id` and then the API will return the data and our class instance will have these books.

The main reason this class is built like this is because the API is designed with an endpoint for each entity of data and we have to use multiple methods to get the whole data set, so for example if we wanted to retrieve the authors for the books we'd use a method like:

```rb
def with_authors(&block)
  books.each do |book|
    book.author = API.find_author_by_id(@token, @scope, book.author_id, &block)
  end

  self
end
```

The class is used in our application like so:

```rb
book_manger = BookManager.new(current_user.token, params[:scope])
                         .find_book_by_id(params[:id])
@book = book_manger.books.first
```

Or if we wanted the authors as well, we'd chain the methods:

```rb
book_manger = BookManager.new(current_user.token, params[:scope])
                         .find_book_by_id(params[:id])
                         .with_authors
@book = book_manger.books.first
```

And then we can access the data like:

```rb
@book.book_name
@book.author.author_name
```

Hopefully this all makes sense up until now...

---

So when we're writing RSpec tests for our app we want to mock out this `BookManager` so that it doesn't call the actual API.

For example here I have created double's of the books and told RSpec to return the books (with the book inside) when the `find_book_by_id` method is called.

```rb
book = double('book', book_id: 1, book_name: 'Book Name')
books = double('books', books: [book])
allow_any_instance_of(BookManager).to receive(:find_book_by_id).and_return(books)
```

However what I've found is that `books` accessor always returns it's default value of `[]`, so it's not actually setting the `@books` inside the class instance using my mock.

Instead, I've had to mock the API itself:

```rb
book = double('book', book_id: 1, book_name: 'Book Name')
books = double('books', books: [book])
allow(API).to receive(:find_book_by_id).and_return(books)
```

Which then allows me to use the `BookManager`... which could be argued as better practice as it's the API that needs mocking... but some of our other classes have a lot of nested API methods and I was hoping to keep the mocking simpler and only mock the classes used in the code rather than the nested methods below... **I'm also curious how I could do it!**

I'm assuming the mocking of the `BookManager` doesn't work as expected because I've mocked the method (in this case `find_book_by_id) which is what actual sets` @books`and therefore the accessor/instance variable is always empty... so in this particular case, using`.and_return(books)` doesn't actually return the books...

Seems what I need to do is return the instance of that class rather than just the `books` but I'm not sure exactly how I'd do that using RSpec mocks.

Comment: Does the following work: `let(:stub_manager) { instance_double(BookManager, find_book_by_id: books) }`
`allow(BookManager).to receive(:new).and_return(stub_manager)`

Comment: You could define a [fake implementation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs) for the methods, as needed by the specs? Like: `allow(book_manager).to receive(:find_book_by_id) { |id| book_manager.instance_variable_set(:'@books', books); book_manager }`?

Comment: Upvoted question for putting in the effort to write a clear, well structured question with the perfect amount of code to illustrate the problem. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about why the stub you've tried does not work. Since you are mocking the method that sets the instance variable, any time you access the instance variable through the `attr_accessor` you're going to get the initialized value rather than the mocked return value of `find_books_by_id`.

You are also correct in your instinct to not mock the API. If your goal is to test the code that uses the `BookManager`, then you should mock/stub the `BookManager` interface not its subordinate objects. In fact, your tests should not know anything about the internal structure of the `BookManager`, including whether or not it maintains state. That would be a violation of the Law of Demeter.

But, your tests do know about the public interface of the `BookManager`, including the `books` attr_accessor. The solution to your problem is to stub that, and mock all the other methods with a null object.

Like this:

```
let(:book_manager) { double(BookManager).as_null_object }
let(:book) { double('book', book_id: 1, book_name: 'Book Name') }
let(:books) { [book] }

before do
  allow(BookManager).to receive(:new).and_return(book_manager)
  allow(book_manager).to receive(:books).and_return(books)
end
```

Now, calls to `find_book_by_id` and `with_authors` will execute and return the null object (self, essentially) which works perfectly with your method chaining. And, you can stub just the methods you care about, like `books`.

Plus, you'll get bonus points for not using `allow_any_instance_of` which should be reserved for testing the thorniest of legacy code.

Docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/null-object-doubles

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll give that try. Interesting that you avoid the use of `allow_any_instance_of` as we use that loads (is that really considered bad practice?). Btw if we did want to use that... how would you mock the data the same the way as you have done but using `allow_any_instance_of`... just curious for learning. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the above and RSpec gave the error: `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: the BookManager class does not implement the instance method: ancestors. Perhaps you meant to use 'class_double` instead?``

Comment: Try using “double” instead of “instance_double”.

Comment: Also, here's the RSpec docs on the use of `allow_any_instance_of` and why they recommend you avoid it: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: As for how I would do it with `allow_any_instance_of`, I wouldn't. I reserve the use of that command for the thorniest of legacy code problems. Even then, if I can avoid it, I do.